# JNI: global reference to a jarray in C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm writing a java program which makes extensive use of native methods and JNI implemented in C++. On the C++ side, I have a local reference to a `jarray` which I would like to convert to a global reference.  Simple, I think: call `env->NewGlobalRef(array_ref)`.  And, indeed, this works --- but the result is a `jobject`, not a `jarray`.  Is it safe to downcast this back to a `jarray`? If not, can I recover a `jarray` from it?  Note that I'm in C++, where these are not just typedefs of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be safe since a `jarray` is a subtype of `jobject` [[ref]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) and is basically a pointer. Here's the relevant code from `jni.h` under the `#ifdef __cplusplus` part:

```
class _jobject {};
class _jclass : public _jobject {};
:
:
class _jarray : public _jobject {};
class _jbooleanArray : public _jarray {};
:

typedef _jobject *jobject;
:
typedef _jarray *jarray;
typedef _jbooleanArray *jbooleanArray;
:
```

As is evident, these are just dummy classes to implement subtyping and `jarray` and `jobject` are of type `_jobject*` and `_jarray*` and the class `_jarray` just inherits from `_jobject` to evince the `is-a` relationship.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the C++ standard would be upset by this downcasting in general if the original pointer wasn't actually of the derived type -- for example dynamic_cast chokes on this.  If you're basically saying that this isn't really a __jarray *or* a __jobject but rather some other internal pointer type, then I guess that's fine but .... ew, gross java.

Comment: @MatthewMilano I won't comment on the aesthetics, but casting a `jobject` to `jarray` is JNI's equivalence of `Object` -> `Array`.  Just as every construct in the Java world is an `Object`, so is `jobject` the _base_ type for all JNI constructs. That's how JNI works. I'm not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: Also, `dynamic_cast` won't be applicable here. since it only works for classes with virtual polymorphism.